# picture privacy using htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am making a social networking website where people can post photos that only their friends can see. I store images in a folder called photos. I want the images to be only viewed through html tag img so if someone types the img url directly in the browser I want it to return 403/404 or whatever. how can I get this done with htaccess?

Comment: Search for prevent image hotlinking. Not sure exactly how to do it, but that will get you some relevant answers.

Comment: Your proposed method won't get the job done.  You need to handle this sort of access at the application layer.  Otherwise, someone can easily spoof a referrer header and rip all of your images.

Comment: You can't reliably tell the difference between a browser making a GET request as part of a page load, and someone putting the URL into a browser address box. Trying to apply security with .htaccess will probably defeat you anyway. You'd be better pointing your image at a PHP script which can check login status and access rights before returning the image.

Comment: @Mike - You can a little with the Http "Referer" header, but it's unreliable at best.

Comment: @LukeBriggs - I quote: "You can't reliably tell..."

Comment: Hehe I was just editing - I re-read and spotted that; my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant do that with htaccess as aptly pointed out by other answers, you can however create a php script that controls who can access images, we'll call it `imgsrc.php`

```
$file = $_GET['file'];

if(user_allowed_access($file)){
  $ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);
  header('Content-type: image/' . $ext);
  readfile($file);
} else {
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  readfile('some/default/file.png');
}
```

Then for your `<img>` tag have src

```
<img src="/imgsrc.php?file=path/to/image.png" />
```

Then in your `.htaccess` for the image directory put

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

none of the above is tested but you should get the idea

Comment: Be careful with this; depending on your user_allowed_access function, there may be nothing stopping someone using relative paths to get your server to provide things that should be hidden:   <img src="/imgsrc.php?file=../../systemfile.dat" />

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware (someone please correct me if you know otherwise), **that's not possible with htaccess** as it would need to know who you're friends are to let them see the image.

Instead, you would have to do some cookie authentication with something like PHP to find out who the requester is, then check if their friends/ mutual friends etc with the image owner, and serve up the image that way if they are allowed to see it. This is an *extremely* taxing process though (it's hard enough serving static images as they are!), so the general technique is use long, awkward URLs so they can't be guessed by somebody and leave it at that (i.e. allow what you're trying to prevent).

Alternatively, again using PHP, check the HTTP_REFERER header. If requesting from within the page, it will be set to your pages URL. Otherwise it will be blank or something else. This is unreliable though - some browsers don't send it at all and it can be easily faked anyway.

Alternatively you could enforce a time window, where images can only be requested within say 10 seconds of the initial page load. This is bad for people on slow connections though.

*Fundamentally there's nothing stopping someone taking a screenshot, or a popular one on many imaging sites, straight taking a photo of the screen.*

Comment: I just want the .htaccess to make image only visible through img tag not through url directly in browser

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible either, as htaccess can't tell the difference between an img tag and a tab - You could however look at the Http Referer header, which will be set to your main page when in an img tag, and blank for a tab, but it can be very easily spoofed.